# ALSA re-enter to callback during callback execution

Tags: c++, linux, audio, alsa

My application uses ALSA with callbacks facility to play selected piece of sound. Sometimes it just hangs. I was debugging it hardly 2 days, and finally found that ALSA's callback function invoked while it is executing already. I caught this using:

```
void MyALSACallback()
{
    std::cout << "1"; std::cout.flush();
    // ... snd_pcm_writei() call ... //
    // ... no any returns ... //
    std::cout << "2"; std::cout.flush();
    return;
}
```

The application hangs when i have sequence "11" printed. The "121212..." is on console while application is alive and sound is playing.

How that may happen?

Comment: What is your buffer size ? Maybe it is too small, hence the very frequent callback...

Comment: 940 frames (frame=sizeof(short)*channels). But how it is possible that ALSA invoke the same function 2 times concurrently? Is ALSA running 2 threads for my single playback? That is most interesting question - why it is possible but not "why this happened".

Comment: My ALSA knowledge is very rusty but here are my thoughts. I think your frame size is very small. Are you sure std::cout.flush does not call system function sync ? it looked suspicious to me. I do not think ALSA runs a thread in your process, most probably it calls your callback function through a signal...

Comment: Re-entering to callback while it is running means 2 parallel execution flows = 2 threads. Very suspicious. Yes, my period size if small, but ALSA known for small period size in comparison to WinAPI (waveXXX-functions). The maximum period size is something like 1600 frames (now - 940). Don't know how std::cout.flush() works and why you asking about system function sync? If you are talking about sync that writes data to disks - no.

Comment: There are no threads that calls your callback, the ALSA signal handler calls your callback. std::cout.flush() flushes a buffer to a char device that is displayed on an xterm window. This is a long road to go from inside a signal handler. Browse this page and search for the word 'signal'. http://alsa.opensrc.org/HowTo_Asynchronous_Playback

Comment: I think the code that calls your callback is this (snd_async_handler) :: http://alsa-lib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.8-3/async_8c-source.html

Comment: Ok, but i don't get the logic of such behavior. Why the handler is called 2 times in parallel? How it is possible?

Comment: Your callback can not return on time. It takes much longer to execute than expected/allowed...

Comment: By the way, no any long operations now - the problem is the same. Ok, lets assume it takes longer, but how it is possible to re-enter to the same function? Why the kernel (or who is the caller of signal handler) doesn't wait return? It is not clean why that possibility (to re-enter) exists in the system.

Comment: As I said earlier :: std::cout.flush() flushes a buffer to a char device that is displayed on an xterm window (which is handled by the xterm process). This may (probably will) require the kernel to switch execution context to another process while your execution point is still in your callback. This alone will take much much longer than you assume. You are not allowed to do much in a callback and you certainly should not do any stdio and flush operations. As signals are asynchronous they can do what you call re-entry. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Risks

Comment: Ok, i removed any flushes and printings, the problem is the same. Ok, maybe i should use mutex? :) It is interesting, but ALSA manuals don't mention this possibility (re-enter) at all...

Comment: I remember using buffers that are 1 second long, who don't you give it a try ? Just 940 sample seems too small to me and what reason do you have to keep it that small ?

Comment: ALSA does not allow to send more than this at a time. Or maybe 1500 frames. Will clarify this later. WinAPI do allow to send up to several seconds at a time, but not ALSA. And having 940, the callback sent 46 times per second (44100/940). I think that 1/46 of second it TOO LONG time for my 1.86 GHz core2duo CPU T5600 to process my simple handler :)

Comment: I think you mis-configure ALSA or you are confusing hardware and software parameters. This problem has nothing to do with your CPU as there was a time when we listened to MP3 without any click/noise on 486 systems...